# Relative path doesn't work in Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm running into a strange problem with AJAX. I have a HTML page which calls an AJAX function on this page:

public_html/test/books.html

The AJAX file I'm trying to call is on this page:

public_html/lists/include/vote_up.php

I'm trying to inclue it in the only logical way, which is this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../lists/include/vote_up.php?id="+id,true);
```

But the request never reaches the PHP file. What am I doing wrong? On that same books.html page, I have several includes from the 'lists/includes' folder which work, for instance:

```
include('../lists/include/functions.php');
```

Here's the updated function using an absolute path:

```
function voteUp(id){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
     else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("item_voting"+id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","mydomain.com/lists/include/vote_up.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just `/lists/include/vote_up.php?id=whatever`, starting with a slash like that? That's what I always use, but I forget if this requires additional server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path `something.com/lists/include/voice_up.php` should work, now that I think, because you are still in the public_html folder even the relative path you provided should work well, because I often use them for images and .css files. I suggest posting more code to make it clear.

Answer (score -2):

The issue here is that you are using system paths in the xmlhttp.open function. Javascript is executed client side, so system paths mean nothing. The .. notation is unusable in this context. You are supposed to provide a URL. If you were to do `domainname.domain/lists/include/voice_up.php` instead, it would work just fine.

Comment: I don't think that's right, because 1) I have AJAX functions working with '../etc' paths, and 2) Using an absolute path gives a Javascript error.

Comment: Did you even read documentation? It clears says URL. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29 Javascript is run in the client's web browser. Your file system paths have no meaning.

Comment: Using domainname.com/lists/include/vote_up.php does not work.

Comment: Then you have another error. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: None anymore, the error was caused by adding 'http://' to the beginning of the URL. I am adding the full AJAX function to my question.

Comment: You can use relative path in javascript ... it's not the best way, but you can.